# New kubernetes install has remnants of old cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

I did a complete tear down of a v1.13.1 cluster and am now running v1.15.0 with calico cni v3.8.0. All pods are running:

```
[gms@thalia0 ~]$ kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-59f54d6bbc-2mjxt      1/1     Running   0          7m23s
calico-node-57lwg                             1/1     Running   0          7m23s
coredns-5c98db65d4-qjzpq                      1/1     Running   0          8m46s
coredns-5c98db65d4-xx2sh                      1/1     Running   0          8m46s
etcd-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu                      1/1     Running   0          8m5s
kube-apiserver-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu            1/1     Running   0          7m46s
kube-controller-manager-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu   1/1     Running   0          8m2s
kube-proxy-lg4cn                              1/1     Running   0          8m46s
kube-scheduler-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu            1/1     Running   0          7m40s
```

But, when I look at the endpoint, I get the following:

```
[gms@thalia0 ~]$ kubectl get ep --namespace=kube-system
NAME                      ENDPOINTS                                                           AGE
kube-controller-manager   <none>                                                              9m46s
kube-dns                  192.168.16.194:53,192.168.16.195:53,192.168.16.194:53 + 3 more...   9m30s
kube-scheduler            <none>                                                              9m46s
```

If I look at the log for the apiserver, I get a ton of TLS handshake errors, along the lines of:

```
I0718 19:35:17.148852       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 10.x.x.160:45042: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0718 19:35:17.158375       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 10.x.x.159:53506: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

These IP addresses were from nodes in a previous cluster. I had deleted them and done a `kubeadm reset` on all nodes, including master, so I have no idea why these are showing up. I would assume this is why the endpoints for the `controller-manager` and the `scheduler` are showing up as `<none>`.

Comment: You say a complete tear down but have you removed `.kube` and made sure the docker containers are stopped?

Comment: Hmmm... no I did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to completely wipe your cluster you should do next:

1) Reset cluster

```
$sudo kubeadm reset (or use appropriate to your cluster command)
```

2) Wipe your local directory with configs

```
$rm -rf .kube/
```

3) Remove  `/etc/kubernetes/`

```
$sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
```

4)And one of the main point is to get rid of your previous etc state configuration.

```
$sudo rm -rf /var/lib/etcd/
```